# Rails 5 sending HTML email with an attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, html-email, email-attachments

So in my app a user can create the body of an email they send to "contacts" they have in the app.

The app uses a CKEditor textbox for the user to enter the body of the email.
They can also attach a file to the email.

Using this code the email gets sent the file is attached properly but all of the HTML tags are visible in the body of the email.

**Controller**

```
@file = EmailFile.create! file: params[:attachment]
@attachment_path = @file.file.url
@file_name = @file.file_file_name

email_params = {
  to: email_recipients,
  from: current_user.email,
  subject: params[:email_subject],
  body: params[:email_body]
}

CustomMailer.send_individual_email(email_params, @attachment_path, @file_name).deliver_now!
```

**Mailer**

```
  def send_individual_email(email_params, attachment_path, file_name)
    if file_name.present?
      open_file = open(attachment_path)
      attachments[file_name] = File.read(open_file)
    end

    mail(to: email_params[:to],
         from: email_params[:from],
         subject: email_params[:subject],
         body: email_params[:body])
  end
```

**send_individual_email.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns=3D"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir=3D"auto">
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
</head>
<body>
  <%= body.html_safe %>
</body>
</html>
```

*there is also a send_individuial_email.text.erb file.*

If I change the Mailer to add the content_type, the attached file becomes a garbled string of text in the email but the HTML tags properly format the text

**Mailer**

```
mail(to: email_params[:to],
     from: email_params[:from],
     subject: email_params[:subject],
     content_type: 'text/html',
     body: email_params[:body])
```

The Rails 5.0.1 app is hosted on Heroku and is using Sendgrid to send the emails.

I have tried changing the content_type as well as removing the .html_safe in the view.

I can get the email to work fine with an attachment and plain text for the body, or no attachment and marked up text showing in the body but not both at the same time.

I know there must be something I'm doing wrong.

How can I send an email with markup text in the body with an attached file?

Thanks!